# Cómo registrar a un usuario Kotlin SQL

Tags: android-studio, postgresql

lo que quiero es hacer que del registro de un usuario que reciba solamente nombre y contraseña logren guardarse los datos en la base de datos y pueda iniciar sesión. Cree otro activity donde se van a ingresar los datos de usuario y contraeña, y a partir de este quiero que los envíe a la Base de datos.

Utilicé código SQL para crear mi base de datos, la única manera en la que puedo ingresar a un nuevo usuario es registrándolo directamente en la tabla mediante PostgreSQL

Mi código para el inicio de sesión es este:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val LOG_ACTI = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
    private val servicioURL = "http://rigel.fca.unam.mx/~li313335952/WebServices/login.php"
    private lateinit var usuario: EditText
    private lateinit var password: EditText
    private lateinit var ingresar: Button
    private lateinit var progreso: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var registrar: Button
    private lateinit var usuarioLogin: UsuarioLogin

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        usuario = findViewById(R.id.usuario)
        password = findViewById(R.id.contrasenia)
        ingresar = findViewById(R.id.ingresar)
        registrar = findViewById(R.id.resgistrar)
        progreso = findViewById(R.id.progreso)

        ingresar.setOnClickListener {
            usuarioLogin = UsuarioLogin(usuario, password, progreso)
            val valido = usuarioLogin.execute().get()
            if(valido) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario es valido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                var dato = usuario.text.toString()
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ZonaActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("Nombre", dato)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario y/o password es incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        registrar.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,
                RegitrarActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    inner class UsuarioLogin(usuario: EditText, password: EditText, progreso: ProgressBar): AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        val usuario: EditText = usuario
        val password: EditText = password
        val progreso: ProgressBar = progreso

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            progreso.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean {
            var respuesta = false
            try {
                val builder = Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("usuario", usuario.text.toString())
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", password.text.toString())
                val parametros = builder.build().encodedQuery
                respuesta = enviarPeticionJSON(servicioURL, parametros!!.toString())

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(LOG_ACTI, "No se puede hacer la conexión al URL" + e.message)
            }
            return respuesta
        }

        private fun enviarPeticionJSON(ruta: String, parametros: String): Boolean {
            var json: JSONObject? = null
            var respuesta = false
            try {
                val url = URL(ruta)
                val con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                con.requestMethod = "POST"
                con.connectTimeout = 10000
                con.readTimeout = 12000
                con.doOutput = true

                val out = con.outputStream
                out.write(parametros.toByteArray())
                out.flush()
                out.close()

                if (con.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    try {
                        val data = con.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
                        json = JSONObject(data)
                        val id = json.getInt("id")
                        respuesta = json.getBoolean("valido")
                        Log.d(LOG_ACTI, "valido=$respuesta, id=$id")

                    } catch (jsone: JSONException) {
                        Log.e(LOG_ACTI, "No se puede leer el JSON: " + jsone.message)
                    }
                }

            } catch (ioe: Exception) {
                Log.e(LOG_ACTI, "Problemas de I/O: " + ioe.message)
            }
            return respuesta
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean?) {
            if(result == true){
                progreso.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                finish()
            } else {
                progreso.visibility = View.GONE
                password.error = "Usuario y/o password es incorrecto"
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled() {
            progreso.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

}
```

Cree un archivo para el login en el servidor que estoy utilizando, tengo entendido que para registrar a un usuario debo crear un nuevo archivo PHP para indicarle a la base de datos en donde registraré a dicho usuario.
Agradecería mucho que me mostraran un ejemplo de cómo podría hacerlo en Android Studio.